# VB.net How to move to the last record

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the following code. Please help me on how to get the last record of the records.

```
Dim DteQry As New OdbcCommand
DteQry.CommandText = "select distinct trn_date from order_data order by trn_date asc limit 30;"

Conn.open()
DteQry.Connection = Conn

Dim qryRdr As OdbcDataReader
qryRdr = DteQry.ExecuteReader()

If qryRdr.HasRows() Then

    Dim StartDte = qryRdr.GetValue(0)
    TextBox2.Text = qryRdr.GetValue(0)
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: You haven't really thought that through, have you?  Why sort the data in ascending order and then try to get the last record when you could sort in descending order and get the first?  In fact, why not use `TOP` or the equivalent for your database if it has one and just retrieve one record in the first place?

Comment: I want the last record of the number of records opted, that is the reason i have given such a query

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the `LIMIT` part but even then, you can still use that as an inner query and then have an outer query order in the opposite direction and then get the first record.  Use a bit of logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this...

You cannot get the row count directly from `OdbcDataReader`. So just create the dataTable `dt` and load the dataset from reader to `dt`. Get the row count from datatable and then you can get last record as below.

```
If qryRdr.HasRows() Then                
            Dim dt As DataTable
            dt.Load(qryRdr)
            Dim StartDte = dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count-1).item(0)
            TextBox2.Text = dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count-1).item(0)
            Exit Sub
     End If
```

Comment: Tried but this code give the error message {"No data exists for the row/column."}

Answer (score 0):

```
dim Last_record as integer
Dim tb As DataTable
dim dp = New OleDbDataAdapter("select max(ID) from tb2", cn)
dp.Fill(tb)
If Not IsDBNull(tb.Rows(0).Item(0)) Then Last_record = tb.Rows(0).Item(0)
tb.clear
```

Comment: Code only answers are generally considered low quality. Could you add an explanation to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE id=(SELECT max(id) FROM TableName);
```